# Measuring a 2 cell 18650 battery from ATMega328P

Tags: arduino, atmega, lithium-ion

I'm using an ATMega 328P (which will be running arduino code) as part of a project (a bicycle lighting system). It runs off of 2 Li-Ion cells, which both are step-up-regulated to 12V for the lighting, and run off of a linear VReg for the logic (the ATMega).

I thought it might be better to measure the voltage of both cells semi-individually instead of just getting a collective voltage for the battery. My plan was to measure the cell that is closer to ground using an analog-in pin, and then measuring the entire battery using a voltage divider, obtaining the value for the second one by subtraction.

I thought this may be useful if, for example, one cell in the battery fails, or was charged unevenly and starts to go dead earlier than the other.

Of course, I worry about frying the pin by directly measuring a battery, or causing an inaccurate reading due to something I hadn't thought of.

Is this even necessary? Would measuring the entire battery be sufficient? The individual cells have a protection circuit, so they should shut off if they go under the critical charge level. Is there an easy way to recognize from the battery voltage that one of the two cells is almost depleted that doesn't rely on them both being at the same charge level initially? They are individual 18650s (and at the moment I only have a 1 cell charger). Will state of charge imbalance cause any other problems not compensated by measuring each voltage individually?

Comment: Why not use op amps running off the 12V to scale them to manageable/measurable levels?

Comment: They are both at measurable voltage levels, as the "lower" cell won't be higher than 4.2V by itself and the full battery will be voltage divided down to similar. I worry about the current from the cell frying the pin. Op amps would probably work to isolate the voltage and prevent that, but are personally undesirable because I'd have to go out and get them...I don't have any lying around. That's not to say it's not a consideration. I'm pretty new at all this so mostly I'm trying to see if there's some problem I've overlooked before I burn out a chip or make a terrible design.

Comment: There's no way for a current supply to fry an input pin like that, since the pin will only ever draw what it needs. And using op amps will reduce the current draw (especially as a voltage follower) as well as isolate the top cell from the voltage on the bottom cell.

Comment: So, if I hook the battery's positive terminal directly to the ATMega's input pin, it shouldn't harm the chip/pin? Since the ATMega is run through a linear Vreg, does it already have a sufficiently isolated voltage reference for accurate measure?

Comment: No input, not even the ADC input, can be much higher than Vdd. The ATmega does not have an voltage reference high enough to measure a Li-ion cell. It is possible to use the cell as the reference and then convert the internal reference, but you have two cells that you need to measure independently.

Comment: I thought, under normal operation with a 5V supply on the ATMega, the ADC can measure up to the 5V of the supply, which would put the voltage reference high enough to measure the cell that is at ground. Then the battery can be measured with a voltage divider, and the voltages calculated and subtracted to get the second cell voltage. Is there something incorrect in this thinking?

Comment: Sure, but then a) you're at the mercy of how accurate your supply is, and b) you lose precision on the voltage of the top cell.

Comment: And c) you lose out on being able to use a lower supply voltage which would let you reduce the power needed by the MCU (although using a linear regulator will chew it up anyways).

Comment: I should be able to get a resolution of approximately 5mV for the lower cell and 10mV for the upper cell, which I don't think is half bad? I guess I'd be at the mercy of the accuracy of the supply for anything I did unless I used the built in bandgap ref (which would require voltage dividers most definitely). Would an opamp circuit draw much extra current? I've been trying to milliamp-pinch as I want it to run 5-10 hours per charge.

Comment: I was going to write something about only the leakage current being drained on a voltage follower on the bottom cell, but there's the op amp supply to worry about as well. As long as you use a low power op amp I can't see that being too much of an issue. The top cell would need a few milliamps extra in order to subtract the two voltages. Scaling the voltages down in a second stage (or even in the first, for the top cell) may use a little as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far. I'm certainly considering the op-amps (part of the reason I might seem reluctant is I really don't want to do another order, or get extremely overpriced parts from Radio Shack). I know it's kind of funny that I'm using a linear vreg and want to save power, but I thought that the linear reg would be more stable voltage-wise and I would try and minimize the current draw at 5V. Buck regulators aren't perfect either after all, and are substantially more complex.

Comment: You didn't hear this from me, but most op amp manufacturers have a free sample program. You can't (or at least *shouldn't*) resell the product manufactured using samples, but it's an decent way to figure out what's what. But make sure you only sample items that distributors have a decent stock of.